# Acces searchform Runtime Error 2185 when no results

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form which shows all the entries of a table with a few filters on the top.

I have a text field where I can put in the name and every time the content of the field is changed, it reruns the query and brings the focus back to the field.

Code:

```vb
Private Sub FilterName_Change()
Me.Requery
Me.FilterName.SetFocus
Me.FilterName.SelStart = Nz(Len(Me.FilterName), 0)
Me.FilterName.SelLength = Nz(Len(Me.FilterName), 0)
End Sub
```

and here is part of the query behind it:

```sql
WHERE
    tbl_geraete.Geraetename Like "*" &[forms]![frm_geraete]![FilterName] & "*" 
  OR
    IsNull([forms]![frm_geraete]![FilterName])<>False
```

This works perfectly. I can keep typing and it will alway show the relevant entries. However, when I type in something and it doesn't find any entries I get the error:

> Runtime Error 2185 You can't reference a propert or method for a
>   control unless the control has focus.

If I understand this correctly, then somehow `set.focus` isn't working properly when there are no entries shown in the form. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe when a form ends up with an empty recordset it hides all the controls. I was not able to find a way around it, so I put a check where if there are no entries then remove the filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if your Forms-Proptery`AllowAdditions`is set to`False`. If no records match the filter, a new, empty record is shown (you can check by adding a watch on`Me`and a breakpoint after`Me.requery`. If you have set`AllowAdditions`to`True`, `Me.NewRecord`is`True`(-1)). If that is forbidden, an error occurs.

You can avoid that error by setting`AllowAdditions`to`True`or checking the`.RecordCount`. If no records, don't set`.SelStart`and`.SelLength`

```vb
Private Sub FilterName_Change()
With Me
    .Requery
    With .FilterName
        .SetFocus
        If Me.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
            .SelStart = Len(.Text)
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End If
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Keep in mind, that a`Requery`executes the whole query again, which may lead to lagging if query execution time is longer than a 500ms. To avoid`Requery`use a`Filter`that will reuse the recordset and skip the`WHERE`-Expression in SQL-Statement.

```vb
Private Sub FilterName_Change()
With Me
    .Dirty = False
    .Filter = "tbl_geraete.Geraetename LIKE '*" & .FilterName.Value & "*' OR " & Len(.FilterName.Value & vbNullString) & " = 0"
    .FilterOn = True
    With .FilterName
        .SetFocus
        If Me.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
            .SelStart = Len(.Text)
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End If
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

To keep your code simple, avoid checks for not false (`<>False`), instead just check if expression is`True`.`If IsNull([forms]![frm_geraete]![FilterName]) Then`and in sql, prefer sql-expression over vba-function:`[forms]![frm_geraete]![FilterName] Is Null`